# split file by line. filename determined by first word

Tags: bash, file, split

i have a big text file with lines:

```
Gen.1.1 in the beginning...     
Gen.1.2 and earth was...  
Rev.22.20   he talks...
```

i would like to split the file by line, where the filename should be the first string.

gen.1.1.txt should contain:

```
Gen.1.1 in the beginning...
```

gen.1.2.txt should contain:

```
Gen.1.2 and earth was...
```

rev.22.20.txt should contain:

```
Rev.22.20   he talks...
```

i've already tried the basic split (of course, file name is not ideal):

```
awk '{print > substr($0, 0, 1)}' file
```

Comment: Have you looked up how substr works, because it looks like you don't understand it.

Comment: Do you need an awk solution? Else you could try something like `while read a; do echo $a| cut -d" " -f2- >> $(echo $a | cut -d" " -f1) ; done < file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
awk '{ print >> $1".txt" ; close($1".txt") }' myfile
```

*edited* (incorporated comment by OP suggesting file should be included)

Comment: tnx. that does waht i want. unfortunately afer 1000 lines, awk says: cannot open "file.txt" for output (Too many open files).

Comment: i fixed it by closing each file: awk '{ print > $1".txt"; close($1".txt")}' input.txt

Answer (score 0):

When trying the accepted answer, I received the following error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token myfile

The syntax error is resolved by using:

```
awk '{ print >> $1".txt" ; close($1".txt") }' myfile
```

If you don't want the string being used as the filename to be included in the file text, use:

```
awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2)) >> $1".txt"; close($1".txt")}' myfile
```